# Can I make html table into image to embed into pdf

Tags: php, html, image, html-table, gd

I have been reading about this but I have to do some thing. I have a table with diagonal text in the heading columns and horizontal text in the rows. I was able to make text diagonal using CSS rotation thing, table data is coming from db and I want to generate the same html into the pdf. I don't know who to write diagonal text in the pdf. The solution is to create an image of the visible html table with data and then store it and then make pdf and embed that image there. I have been reading the GD library but how can I make table in GD library I am stuck , Stack Overflow is the last resort. Please help.

Comment: This is actually somewhat complex.  Using the GD library, you can create images for the angled heading text, then using a library like FPDF, you can assemble the images and text in a PDF.  I am not at a place where I can readily assemble examples, and it would frankly take a bit of trial and error (FPDF can be tricky to work with).  Hopefully, between this info, Google research, and any answers you get here, you can put it together.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ezpdf class http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/readme.pdf. they got some sample code to rotate text and how to embed image into pdf. 
example

```
for ($angle=0;$angle<360;$angle=$angle+20){
  $r=rand(0,100)/100;
  $g=rand(0,100)/100;
  $b=rand(0,100)/100;
  $pdf->setColor($r,$g,$b);
  $pdf->addText(300+cos(deg2rad($angle))*40,300-
sin(deg2rad($angle))*40,20,$demotext,$angle);
{
$pdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go directly from your HTML code to PDF, and if you need something entirely in PHP you can try [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf). The 0.6.0 release will include CSS transform support.

Answer (score 1):

For image generation in PHP you can use GD functions (fast) or iMagick (not so wide spread, docs are WorkInProgress, but you could do almost anything you can imagine with it).

GD should be enough.

A simple idea about making text diagonal would be to just rotate the image, once you output text from the db onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Use wkhtmltoimage or wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this only once or does this need to be an ondemand service? If not why not just load the html page take a screenshot and crop it down to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to convert HTML directly to a PDF document, you might want to try a PDF library for creating the document directly in PHP.  This way you will get more control over what the PDF looks like, and it may be a better solution that trying to convert your HTML output.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php